# Bimodal frequency distribution of size of protein loops

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, proteins

[image: Frequency distribution of size of protein loops]

The graph of number of amino acid (AA) residues in a loop Vs the frequency of their occurrence in proteins largely follows a tending-to-zero pattern. However, there appear to be some specific number of AAs where the frequency suddenly drops, leading to bi- or multi-modality in the plot. Is there some molecular explanation for this, or is it just an artifact?

I’ve attached the figure from a paper with a different research question but the same graph(Figure 2), albeit more detailed. (The same graph can be found in Brandon and Tooze (fig.2.8).) In the [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3628373/#__ffn_sectitle) from which this is taken “A loop structure was defined as any region between two regular secondary structures that was at least three residues in length.”

Comment: Thank you for adding the graph. I have changed the wording to remove "oscillation" which has other connotations, and "probability", as what is plotted is frequency. I have also added a definition of a loop.

Answer (score 3):

> A curve of this type, showing a bi- or multi-modal distribution,
>   suggests two or more constituent species
>   in the population. In this case this is borne out by further analysis
>   in the paper of different types of secondary structure components
>   anchoring the loop, the peak at low numbers of amino acids reflecting
>   the loops connecting β-strands in anti-parallel β-sheets.

The second frame (B) of Figure 2 is shown below (dashed line):

[image: Constituent secondary structures and loop lengths]

Anti-parallel β-sheets are abundant in proteins, and in many — although not all — cases adjacent strands are connected by short (four- or five-amino acid) loops such as the [β-turn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_turn), the [β-hairpin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_hairpin) or the [β-bulge loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_bulge_loop).

Repeating small loops are especially well illustrated in β-sheets displaying [β-meander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_sheet#%CE%B2-meander_motif):

[image: Beta meander]

*The β-meander motif from the outer surface Protein A*

Examples in larger domains of the β-barrel and immunoglobulin type also show some larger loops.

[image: Beta barrel]

*Beta barrel of green fluorescent protein, showing loops at end of strands*

[image: Immunoglobulin beta-sheets]

*Immunoglobulin domain of PDB 5IML showing β-sheet with loops connecting strands*